# server.transfer session issue asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5

I'm using server.transfer to transfer execution of a URL to a dummy page which fetches information from the database. The trouble is that the master page interacts with the session.

global.asax:

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires at the beginning of each request
    If Not (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(Request.Url.LocalPath))) And Request.Url.LocalPath.ToLower().EndsWith(".aspx") Then
        Server.Transfer("/Utility/utilityCMS.aspx", False)
    Else
        'error
    End If
End Sub
```

master page:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(Session("SessionId"))) Then

    Session.Add("SessionId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString)

End If
```

page declaration:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="utilityCMS.aspx.vb" Inherits="utilityCMS" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/main.master" EnableSessionState="True" %>
```

web.config snippet:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="HttpModuleAggregator" type="XPIdea.Web.HttpModuleAggregator,xpidea.web.common" />
</httpModules>
```

I'm getting an error :

```
Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the <configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> section in the application configuration.
```

I should also mention that this same master page works elsewhere in the site. Session is used throughout the site as well (not just in the master page).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Enable Session state in the Master Page page directive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing routine security checks I would suggest using a base page that all of your secure pages can inherit from and doing the checks there instead of bouncing the request to multiple pages on every request.  I can imagine that there is a performance hit for all the overhead.  I saw quite a few issues posted similar to yours but no concrete answer.

Comment: sorry, no luck with this either.